# Setting variables and taking effect in one batch command line

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I just found out that if you do the following:

```
set Variable=Test & echo %Variable%  --Outputs "%Variable%"
echo %Variable%                      --Outputs "Test"
```

The change won't take effect until a new line runs. I need to have it take effect immediately as I need to use it with a very long, one-lined command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delayed expansion or `call echo`:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set var=val&echo !var!

endlocal

set var=val&call echo %%var%%
```

If you have compositions of commands put together with `&` or in brackets the set command will take effect after all of them are executed.So you need or delayed expansion (which will allow you to access the variables with `!` instead of `%`) or call

To enable the delayed expansion in command prompt you need to start like this `cmd /v:on` :

```
>cmd /v:on
>set Variable=Test & echo !Variable!
```

Comment: It worked, but I have no idea how to use it with the rest of the commands. Do I have to put call in front of every command after this? EDIT: I just saw your new comment. Let me try it.